# Switch returning same statement multiple times

Tags: java, return, switch-statement

I'm making a school assignment and this time around I thought about using a switch statement since it looked more efficient.

It's just something basic but if I enter a letter for example and after that number 1 for example it would return case 1 twice?

This is my code for the entire class so far:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

private int option;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t = new Test();
    t.start();
    t.optionMenu();
}

public void start() {
    System.out.println("Make your choice:");
    System.out.println("1: Play");
    System.out.println("2: Options");
    System.out.println("3: Exit");

}

public void optionMenu() {
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.option = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(this.option);
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number");
        optionMenu();
    }


    switch (this.option) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Game starting...");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Loading options");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Game exiting...");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Enter a valid number (1, 2 or 3");
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You need a while statement around your switch statement. Just keep looping until you receive valid input (ie. 1, 2, or 3)

Comment: The loop needs to be around the try catch block holding his scanner if anything, not the switch statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `sc.nextInt()` without first asking `if (sc.hasNextInt())`, you are open to some strange behavior when end-users start typing unexpected input, such as letters. In this case the scanner would not advance its reading pointer, so your program will get stuck reading the same incorrect output.

To fix this issue, add a loop that "clears out" the invalid entry before attempting to read an `int` again, like this:

```
while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.print("You need to enter an integer.");
    sc.nextLine(); // Clear out the bad input
}
int val = sc.nextInt(); // At this point we know that sc.hasNextInt(), because that's the loop condition
```

Another point is that it is not a good idea to do with recursion what can be done with iteration: the recursive call to `optionsMenu` is going to accumulate as many levels of invocation as the number of times the end-user enters an incorrect value, so a very persistent user could theoretically force a stack overflow on your program by entering invalid data repeatedly.

Using the code fragment above would free you from the need to call `optionsMenu` recursively, and also from catching the input exception.

Answer (score 1):

> It's just something basic but if I enter a letter for example and after that number 1 for example it would return case 1 twice?

I'm not sure what you mean here. Firstly, your idea works, this code should be fine!

Second, if you enter anything besides just the number 1, 2, or 3, you will go to the "default:" block of code. Since you are prompting the user again if they fail, typing "a" or "a1" into the prompt just shows the menu again. The user needs to just type "1", "2", or "3" to successfully select a menu option.

Comment: For example: If you press "f" you get prompted with the menu again, if you then press a valid number it would print 2 times the case you have chosen (except 2 which has the exit in it).

Comment: I'm not sure why you are seeing this. He has a break in each case, so it would only print something for his selection once, no matter if the user types "1", "2", or "3".